# What is the equivalent for ga:screenDepth in the GA4 data api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I could not find any dimension to get the screen depth for my app. I checked [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) . Could not find it. It's not there even in GA4 UI .

Answer (score 1):

Definition of **Screen Depth** `ga:screenDepth` is "*The number of screenviews (reported as a string) per session*"

So, you can find similar metrics in **GA4** called **Views per session**
`screenPageViewsPerSession` "*The number of app screens or web pages your users viewed per session*".

Answer (score 1):

> Screen Depth ga:screenDepth  string v3+
> The number of screenviews (reported as a string) per session, useful for historgrams.

I would say one of these depending upon what you are looking for.

> **screenPageViews**
> The number of app screens or web pages your users viewed. Repeated views of a single page or screen are counted. (screen_view + page_view events).

or

> **screenPageViewsPerSession**
> The number of app screens or web pages your users viewed per session. Repeated views of a single page or screen are counted. (screen_view + page_view events) / sessions.

or

> **screenPageViewsPerUser**
> The number of app screens or web pages your users viewed per active user. Repeated views of a single page or screen are counted. (screen_view + page_view events) / active users.

Comment: There is a difference. what you suggested are metrics whereas ga:screenDepth is a dimension. It was helpful to trace the journey of the user . A metric won't be able to give me that.

Comment: This is the closest thing you have